# Avoiding extra use of span

Tags: javascript

My question is that I have an html code `<p> Hello World </p>`

And want to change the css of every letter using JavaScript. Essentially, I will change the background color to make an animation. Is there a way to do this without making a span or some sort of tag around every letter and going through all that struggle?

I have my string array with colors and a method to call the correct color (data-index attribute).

Thanks!

**EDIT:** I have the entire word changing color and thought of an idea by making a function that iterates over the indexes of the innerHTML string and assigns a data-index to the letter's span by editing the function provided below by **Cymen**. Is this a good approach?

Comment: No, you'll have to use spans.

Comment: @Brian is right.  Text nodes provide few CSS hooks.  You're limited to a few pseudo-elements: `first-letter` and `first-line`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to use a JavaScript function to wrap each character in a `<span>`.

```
window.onload = function() { // when everything loads, run the function
     var elem = document.getElementById( "someId" );
     var text = elem.innerHTML; // get the <p>'s text content
     elem.innerHTML = ""; // then make the <p> empty
     for( var i=0; i<text.length; i++ ) { // for each character in the text
           elem.innerHTML += "<span>"+text[i]+"</span>";
     }
};
```

Remember to change "someId" to the id of your `<p>` element.

You can access each individual character inside the `for` loop with `text[i]`.

Answer (score 4):

No, you will need to use a tag that supports `background-color`. You can easily wrap a string of characters in spans like so:

```
function wrapInSpans(string) {
  return '<span>' + string.split('').join('</span><span>') + '</span>';
}
```

Comment: OK Thanks! Is there a reason why they do not make this feature in HTML?

Comment: Also, how do I access the separate characters. Is there an alternative where I can iterate over every span within the `<p> </p>`

Comment: @ytpillai They don't make this a feature in HTML because it's not a particularly common thing to do, and trying to bake in every conceivable feature in makes for a complicated and difficult to learn language. To get the character of the string at index `i`, you can do `string[i]`, or `string.getCharAt(i)`.

Comment: Peter Olson, in this case I will be converting the string to a javascript string. However, there is no way to change the innerHTML of the character at that original string. I can write a function to set a custom attribute data-index to the index of the letter in the string of the tag.

However, is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: @ytpillai You can iterate over the `span`s inside the `p` with `p.getElementsByTagName("span")` (once you have defined `p` in the JavaScript)

Comment: OK thanks very much. That solved all my problems :). Can you post that as a full answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @ytpillai Sorry, I was commuting but the other answer looks good!

Answer (score 1):

This would take quite a bit of code to spell out completely, but, if it's very important in your case to not actually add some type of wrapping element, then I believe this would be possible via a dynamically generated background image.

Roughly the steps would be:

1. Create a `Range` with a start and end around each character in the `.textContent`s of the element you care about.
2. `.getBoundingClientRect()` on each range to get its rendered dimensions.
3. Draw rectangles of the desired color to a `<canvas>`.
4. Export the `<canvas>` as a `data` URI.
5. Use the `data` URI as a `background-image`.
6. Repeat for each block displayed element that you care about.

Be advised that there will, no doubt, be various edge cases in this approach and possible browser support limitations.  Obviously just wrapping each character is a much simpler.

Comment: That's the most explicit and well-explained JavaScript I didn't understand one word of. Haha I'm sorry I'm still a beginner and found a working idea already. I think your idea is more towards a drawn image message or something whereas I simply am using text and CSS